# How to cleanly present different text to users based on user properties?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, rails-i18n, theming, branding

I'm building an app in Rails with SSR ERB views. In the app I'm building, each user is associated with a brand (i.e., a company). Based on the brand the user is associated with, the app must present the "correct" branded experience -- including styling, images, copy, etc. I'd like to figure out a clean way to pull the logic to pick the appropriate copy out of the views.

For example, I'd love to be able to replace:

```
<% if @user.brand_foo? %>
  <h1>This is my favorite brand</h1>
<% else %>
  <h1>No, really, this is my favorite brand</h1>
<% end %>
```

with something like

```
# in some (yml?) file

brand_foo:
  product_page:
    super_good_header: "This is my favorite brand"

brand_bar:
  product_page:
    super_good_header: "No, really, this is my favorite brand"
```

```
# in the view

<h1><%= branded("product_page.super_good_header", @user.brand) %></h1>
```

I've been thinking about leaning on I18n, and having each set of copy live as a locale, but I'm worried that that decision might bite me later down the line when I actually need language localization.

How have you done this in your apps? Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Found a gem that does exactly what I was looking for: https://github.com/ElMassimo/i18n_multitenant

Answer (score 1):

you could have an helper like `user_branded` that would read the yml configuration file and retrieve the correct string based on the path (e.g. split the input string by ".").